# Flexbox or @media

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, media-queries

I am learning responsive web design. I recently learned how to use flexboxes and learned about @media using min-width and max-height to design for tablets and mobile devices. Is one better than the other when it comes to responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox and media queries are two completely different things, and both should be used for responsive web design.

Comment: In what way should they both be used. I would imagine since flexboxes can use the syntax of flex-wrap:wrap and flex-wrap:nowrap this is already enough to create a responsive site?

Comment: the only thing flex-wrap does is wrap elements to a new line basically, when there isn't enough space. This is obviously a simplified explanation of what wrap does. Responsive design also entails resizing and repositioning elements, so flex-wrap can help you reposition elements, but it doesn't resize, and it's not a guarantee that it'll automatically look good.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: np, please mark it as the answer if it has helped you in any way